# Azure blob storage - Performance of prefix filter

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

I'm using Azure blob storage to store items grouped into a simple one-to-many relationship. I want to support up to a million "groups" and each group will have less than 10 items (think of it as a millon orders each with 10 line items).

I'm planning to use a compond key of `<group id>:<item id>` as the blob name so I can easily retrieve all the items for a group with a prefix query. This meets all my requirements from a functional perspective, but I'm trying to find out if it's workable from a performance point of view or whether I need to add some other index to store the relationship.

I've found this page https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/tables/table-storage-design-patterns#compound-key-pattern which recommends the compound key pattern but it is talking about table storage as opposed to blobs. There is also a hint here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-performance-checklist#partitioning which implies that using a prefix filter will be faster than a full scan but, it seems to be more about the way that data is partitioned across servers rather than within a server.